# How do you deploy a Bitcoin-Cash full node on a Cent OS 7 server?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, full-node, centos

I'm looking to compile it on CentOS 7.

Perhaps a guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this deployment guide.

https://github.com/CanadianRepublican/BitcoinCash-Daemon-Deployment-CentOS7

it includes a systemd service file, and a logrotate configuration file